# Sonar scan failing to run

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to run a sonar scan using maven on a multi module project.

The goal fails saying that maven cannot find matching files from the .m2 repo within certain modules of the project and it won't continue with the scan.

Does anyone know what could be causing this??

The error code is similar to:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project : No files nor directories matching  in directory  -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can we get the full error?

Comment: also, did you run 'mvn clean install' before the analysis?